# Asp.net forms authentication in mvc4 - as easy at it seems?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm working on this asp.net mvc4 application, and I'm new to this part of the .net world. I've read a dozen articles and looked through quite a few hours of material on pluralsight, but I can't help but ask the question;
Is webforms authentication as easy to implement on a basic level, as they say? By this I mean registering the global filter and just allowing anonymous access to the actions I want to be publicly available? And then of course, implement the login logic, setting cookies etc.

I guess what I'm trying to convince myself of, is wether or not this is the correct way to start out?

Comment: Yes, it's just as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be a good day at work tomorrow :) Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is easy.

Assume that you will use Basic authentication (to just isolate the problem of creating the Login form).

- Step 1: add a global filter `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`.
- Step 2: add `[AllowAnonymous]` to the controller actions you want to be public.
- Result: the user is requested to enter his credentials when viewing non-public URLs.

Now when this is working, you can set up Forms authentication - besides creating the HTML, it is just a few lines of code mostly centered around `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()`.

Comment: By the way; I've noticed the <authentication mode="Forms"> .. </..> tag in my web.config. What is the difference between using this an adding the global filter?

Comment: the global filter is for authorization (controlling who can access what action). the tag in the config file controls what kind of authentication is used (e.g. how the user is asked for his/her password).